# The safe and standard-compliant way of accessing array of integral type as an array of another unrelated integral type?

Tags: c++, memory, type-conversion, c++17, type-safety

Here's what I need to do. I'm sure it's a routine and recognizable coding task for many C++ developers out there:

```
void processAsUint16(const char* memory, size_t size) {
   auto uint16_ptr = (const uint16_t*)memory;
   for (size_t i = 0, n = size/sizeof(uint16_t); i < n; ++i) {
      std::cout << uint16_ptr[i]; // Some processing of the other unrelated type
   }
}
```

Problem: I'm developing with an IDE that integrates clang static code analysis, and every way of casting I tried, short of `memcpy` (which I don't want to resort to) is either discouraged or strongly discouraged. For example, `reinterpret_cast` is simply banned by the [CPP Core Guidelines](https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-reinterpret-cast.html). C-style cast is discouraged. `static_cast` cannot be used here.

What's the right way of doing this that avoids type aliasing problems and other kinds of undefined behavior?

Comment: `memcpy` is typically the advocated solution. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @PasserBy: it's a performance overhead that totally shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Evidence of there being a "performance overhead" ?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast is simply banned by the CPP Core Guidelines. C-style cast is discouraged.` that's kinda surprising. Usually style guides ban c style casting and discourage reinterpret_cast.

Comment: What about `asm("");`

Comment: @curiousguy: could you expand on your thought? I would hate using assembler in my cross-platform C++ projects, though.

Comment: @user2079303: the first item of https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#SS-type literally says: "Don't use reinterpret_cast".

Comment: @M.M: it's obvious to me that `memcpy` can't _not_ incur a performance overhead as it's a `for` loop of some kind. Isn't that obvious to you? I'm not even mentioning the overhead of calling an extra function as these kinds of functions are typically not `inline`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe you misunderstand how compilation works in C++ . I would recommend trying it out (with optimization enabled) and inspecting the assembly generated; as well as trying benchmarks

Comment: @VioletGiraffe the core guideline also literally says `Don't use C-style (T)expression or functional T(expression) casts: Prefer construction or named casts.` there are places where the core guideline suggests using reinterpret_cast even though it's discouraged.

Comment: @user2079303 `string("")` is not "construction"?

Comment: @curiousguy never mind my last comment; it was wrong. `std::string(x)` is both a functional cast, and a construction. The guideline appears to be unclear whether this is to be avoided, or preferred.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe "_could you expand on your thought?_" Just `asm("");` to prevent the compiler from knowing that you have **not** done a `memcpy`. "_I would hate using assembler_" No assembly code is needed, just a transition to/from ABI. It should allow you to manipulate the objects with another type.

Comment: @M.M: I won't call myself an expert on C++ compilers, but I doubt I misunderstand it so much. That said, you're right, `memcpy` is somehow inlined and optimized away, but I don't understand how the compiler does it even with `-fno-whole-program` since it's not even an inline function, and I don't believe this is a reliable optimization (one that the compiler is guaranteed to do and not just happens to sometimes do when it's in the mood). I'll appreciate if you share you knowledge on this subject. Playground: https://godbolt.org/g/mzL8ok

Comment: @M.M: does the compiler has intrinsic knowledge about `memcpy` so that it doesn't have to see the implementation in order to be able to optimize it away for trivial cases? I looked at the C++14 standard, and `memcpy` doesn't seem to be defined in any detail there, only mentioned as a function that copies bytes.

Comment: The compiler knows about all of the standard library functions (including C ones, they are included by reference from the C++ Standard)

Answer (score 2):

> What's the right way of doing this that avoids type aliasing problems and other kinds of undefined behavior?

You use `memcpy`:

```
void processAsUint16(const char* memory, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += sizeof(uint16_t)) {
        uint16_t x;
        memcpy(&x, memory + i, sizeof(x));
        // do something with x
    }
}
```

`uint16_t` is trivially copyable, so this is fine.

Or, in C++20, with [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) (which awkwardly has to go through an array first):

```
void processAsUint16(const char* memory, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += sizeof(uint16_t)) {
        alignas(uint16_t) char buf[sizeof(uint16_t)];
        memcpy(buf, memory + i, sizeof(buf));

        auto x = std::bit_cast<uint16_t>(buf);
        // do something with x
    }
}
```

---

Practically speaking, compilers will just "do the right thing" if you just `reinterpret_cast`, even if it's undefined behavior. Perhaps something like [`std::bless`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html) will give us a more direct, non-copying, mechanism of doing this, but until then...

Comment: Maybe relevant: [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) will wrap up the `memcpy` operation into a function returning the target integer value

Comment: @M.M Wouldn't help here, we'd need the source type to be `char[2]`?

Comment: The [example here](https://gist.github.com/shadercoder/5be9dcb56cc0cfeab9694404b9e002b9) actually includes intermediate step of copying to a char array ... maybe the final version will include some syntax to avoid that step, since applying it to a char array seems like one of the primary use cases

Comment: @M.M Seems a bit awkward.

Comment: How evil/wrong would `auto& buf = reinterpret_cast<char const(&)[sizeof(uint16_t)]>(*memory);` be? `memory` is already known to be a const char array, but I assume this is still UB..?

Comment: @ildjarn Yeah... still UB, there's no `char[2]` there in the same way that there's no `uint16_t` there.

Comment: @ildjarn you can't avoid the strict aliasing rule with intermediate casts

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be to treat the array of char as a sequence of octets in a defined order.  This obviously doesn't work if it actually can be either order depending on target architecture, but in practise, a memory buffer like this usually comes from a file or a network connection.

```
void processAsUint16(const char* memory, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 2) {
        const unsigned char lo = memory[i];
        const unsigned char hi = memory[i+1];
        const uint16_t x = lo + hi*256;  // or "lo | hi << 8"
        // do something with x
    }
}
```

Note that we do *not* use `sizeof(uint16_t)` here.  `memory` is a sequence of octets, so even if `CHAR_BITS` is 16, there will be two chars needed to hold a `uint16_t`.

This can be a little bit cleaner if `memory` can be declared as `unsigned char` - no need for the definition of `lo` and `hi`.

Comment: Upvote from me. I already have a bunch of macros that do the same thing, albeit in a slightly different context (where byte order inversion might be needed). I was just thinking if I could or should employ this approach when you posted your answer (not much different from plain `memcpy`, though).